# Call base class method after derived class constructor

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
class ClBase{

 public ClBase(){/*do stuff..*/}

 protected postConstructorMethod(){ /*do same stuff for all derived classes*/}

}

class ClInherited:ClBase{

 public ClInherited():base(){/*do stuff..*/}

}
```

I need to do stuff after creating the derived classes.
Is there any way to call "postconstructorMethod()" after the derived class constructor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The class `ClBase` would have no knowledge of the class `ClInherited`; what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to call it on every derived class. If i create a new derived class and i forgot to call that method, i will have a problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call:

`base.postConstructorMethod();`

from your ClInherited class.